# c++ error: ??? does not name a type

Tags: c++, irc

Okay upon running g++ main.cpp -o services

If i do all this in one class lets say .cpp it works fine, but whenever i divide it into another class i keep getting errors, and i really do not understand why, all i did was move the code to another file, and included it.

I am thrown:

```
[Admin@shadowrealm ircservices]$ g++ main.cpp -o services                       
In file included from services.cpp:1:0,
                 from main.cpp:4:
services.h:23:2: error: âSOCKETâ does not name a type
services.h:24:2: error: âHOSTENTâ does not name a type
services.h:25:2: error: âSOCKADDR_INâ does not name a type
```

services.h:

```
#ifndef SERVICES_H
#define SERVICES_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

class services {

public:
    services(); //perhaps init something important here, dunno
    ~services();
    int connect();

private:
    SOCKET sock;
    HOSTENT* host;
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
};

#endif /* SERVICES_H */
```

services.cpp:

```
#include "services.h"

services::services()
{
//do nothing
}

services::~services()
{
//TODO: incase crash, log why.
}

int services::connect()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you define structs called `SOCKET` etc. in main.cpp?

Comment: no, but its defined in services.h so would i need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is case sensitive.
The right is

```
sockaddr_in
hostent
```

If I am not mistaken SOCKET or socket does not name a type at all.

Comment: Oh I see what needs to be done, I just cant use 'socket' directly is all, but thank you!